# Google Sheets, Web scrape Best Buy Price

Tags: json, google-sheets, web-scraping, custom-function

im trying to figure out how to web scrape the price of a product into google sheets.
Before i would use =importrange(A1,B1)

And have A1 = https://www.bestbuy.com/site/asus-17-3-chromebook-intel-celeron-n4500-4gb-memory-32gb-emmc-transparent-silver/6471189.p?skuId=6471189

And have B1 = /html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span[1]

This was done by coping the full Xpath.
So far this has been working but unfortunately it seems like that is no longer a way to do it.

Im trying to do this for both Best Buy and Walmart

if i could have an example for these two links that would be awesome! Thank you in advanced!

Link 1: https://www.bestbuy.com/site/asus-17-3-chromebook-intel-celeron-n4500-4gb-memory-32gb-emmc-transparent-silver/6471189.p?skuId=6471189

Link 2:https://www.walmart.com/ip/Samsung-Chromebook-4-11-6-Intel-Celeron-N4020-4GB-RAM-32GB-SSD-Chrome-OS-Platinum-Titan-XE310XBA/153097702?athbdg=L1300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### bestbuy

In **bestbuy**, you can retrieve all informations in a json by

```
=textjoin(",",,importxml(url,"//script[@type='application/ld+json']"))
```

and especially

```
=regexextract(substitute(textjoin("",,importxml(A1,"//script[@type='application/ld+json']")),char(10),""),"{""@context"":""http://schema.org/"",""@type"":""Product"".*")
```

then you have to parse it (I don't know which informations you wish to retrieve). You can do it by this way

```
function bestbuy(source, code) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(source);
  const v = eval('obj.' + code)
  if (typeof v == 'object') {
    const header = Object.keys(v[0]);
    return [header, ...v.map(o => header.map(h => Array.isArray(o[h]) ? o[h].join(",") : o[h]))];
  } else {
    return v
  }
}
```

use the script this way `=bestbuy(A2,code)` where in A2 you have the result of the importxml function and in code one listed hereafter, for instance `=bestbuy(A2,"offers.highPrice")`

```
/* available informations =
@context
@type
name
image
url
description
sku
gtin13
model
brand.@type
brand.name
aggregateRating.@type
aggregateRating.ratingValue
aggregateRating.reviewCount
offers.@type
offers.priceCurrency
offers.seller.@type
offers.seller.name
offers.lowPrice
offers.highPrice
offers.offers => array
*/
```

[image]

### walmart

In **walmart**, the situation is quite different, you have also a json but you can't fetch through google since there is a captcha.

Comment: Thank you Mike! Im still very new to this. Could you expand a little more into this, i get the first half and made that work. But im having trouble with understanding the parsing part. I get the function goes into google apps script.

But im not sure how to use it past that.  The one thing we were trying to just get originally was just the current price, but if this is able to grab other information at the same time like processor, would you be able to go over it a little more?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have a little simplified the importxml function. Then use the script this way `=bestbuy(A2)` where in A2 you have the result of the importxml function. Let me know if your want more details (the parsing method is a common one when you have an array as here for offers)

Comment: Im sorry, you did say to use that in the original answer, I wasnt grasping that was how making the code and you could name it what everyou wanted.  So far, I figured out how to remove the header, ( we plan to use this for multiple links in a row) 

So my last questions would be, if i only wanted the "299" and nothing else, how would i change the code? 

How am able to have access to the entire list in the first screen shot?

and if wanted to add to the code to grab price, processor, ram, etc, what would be the steps.

I want to be able to apply this in the future and i appreciate this!

Comment: ok, I have added the list of individual informations that you can fetch

Comment: I have simplified the use of the script ...

Comment: It all works!, there is a few links we are using like

 https://www.bestbuy.com/site/hp-11-touch-screen-chromebook-tablet-qualcomm-snapdragon-8gb-memory-64gb-emmc-natural-silver-night-teal/6471019.p?skuId=6471019

that will display everything but the price (using offers.highPrice)  we are using regexextract to get these.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Functions in Google Sheets like IMPORTHTML, IMPORTXML, IMPORTDATA and IMPORTFEED may not retrieve data from a website if the content is added dynamically(using JavaScript). I will reference this [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun):

> If the content is added dynamically (by using Javascript), it can't be imported by using Google Sheets built-in functions. Also if the website webmaster have taken certain measures, this functions will not able to import the data.